# How does contains() in PL-SQL work?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, contains

Have a lot of unnecessary results using contains() method in my query. Don't tell me to use like or something else. It is hardcoded and couldn't be changed.

Comment: can i pass any params into contains to narrow search results to exact result

Comment: Select * from blabla where contains(dFullText, "car")

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Contains is used on text fields that have a 'CONTEXT Index', which indexes a text field for searching.  The standard usage is like this (using the `score` operator to display what is returned from the `contains` clause based on the 1 in `contains` matching the 1 in `score`):

```
SELECT score(1), value
FROM table_name
WHERE CONTAINS(textField, 'searchString', 1) > 0;
```

For data like this in table `table_name`

```
value  |  textField
-------|-----------------------------------------------
A      |   'Here is searchString.  searchString again.'
B      |   'Another string'
C      |   'Just one searchString'
```

That query would return

```
2 A
1 C
```

So contains is similiar to like, but will count how many times a string occurs in a text field.  I couldn't find a resource using Contains the way it is used in the query you posted, but I think that would return rows where `dFullText` has at least one instance of `car` in it, or the equivalent of this sql:

```
Select * from blabla where dFullText like "%car%"
```

[Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_contains_clause.htm) is another source.

Comment: Is there any difference between contains() and instr() ?

Comment: @Rene, yes they are different.  `Contains()` counts how many times a string occurs in a text field and would return that number.  `instr()` searches for a string in a field (or other string) and returns the index of the first search string found (or 0 if it's not found).  See examples of `instr()` at http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php

Answer (score 1):

See this example from [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96517/query.htm)

```
declare 
rowno number := 0; 
   begin 
   for c1 in (SELECT SCORE(1) score, title FROM news 
          WHERE CONTAINS(text, 'oracle', 1) > 0
          ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC) 
   loop 
   rowno := rowno + 1; 
   dbms_output.put_line(c1.title||': '||c1.score); 
exit when rowno = 10; 
end loop; 
end;
```