# Use string contains function in oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an Oracle database and I want to know how can I find rows in a varchar type column where the values of that column has a string which contains some character.

I'm trying something like this (that's a simple example of what I want), but it doesn't work:

```
select p.name
from   person p
where  p.name contains the character 'A';
```

I also want to know if I can use a function like `chr(1234)` where 1234 is an ASCII code instead of the `'A'` character in my example query, because in my case I want to search in my database values where the name of a person contains the character with 8211 as ASCII code.

With the query `select CHR(8211) from dual;` I get the special character that I want.

*Example:*

```
select p.name
from   person p
where  p.name contains the character chr(8211);
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

By *lines* I assume you mean rows in the table `person`. What you're looking for is:

```
select p.name
from   person p
where  p.name LIKE '%A%'; --contains the character 'A'
```

The above is case sensitive. For a case insensitive search, you can do:

```
select p.name
from   person p
where  UPPER(p.name) LIKE '%A%'; --contains the character 'A' or 'a'
```

For the special character, you can do:

```
select p.name
from   person p
where  p.name LIKE '%'||chr(8211)||'%'; --contains the character chr(8211)
```

The `LIKE` operator matches a pattern. The syntax of this command is described in detail in the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm). You will mostly use the `%` sign as it means *match zero or more characters*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works.
And like you said, by lines I meant rows of course, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Glad to help. Yeah, it's easy to go by *tables, rows, columns,* and *cells* - like a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 42):

The answer of ADTC works fine, but I've find another solution, so I post it here if someone wants something different.

I think ADTC's solution is better, but mine's also works.

Here is the other solution I found

```
select p.name
from   person p
where  instr(p.name,chr(8211)) > 0; --contains the character chr(8211) 
                                    --at least 1 time
```

Comment: Use the `code` formatting instead of ***bold italic***. I'd edit it myself but I'd like you to learn =)

Comment: Thanks, I hope is better now :D

Comment: This method is useful when you search for the *`_`* and *`%`* characters in a string. Searching for them with `LIKE` is possible but way more cumbersome.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, because if a subquery is used in place of `chr(8211)`, it still works. When you use like with a subquery and the subquery return 0 results, the like statement would be `like '%%'`, and it will always match, which is probably not intended.

Answer (score 8):

You used the keyword `CONTAINS` in your sample queries and question. `CONTAINS` lets you search against columns that have been indexed with an Oracle*Text full-text index.

Because these columns are full-text indexed, you can efficiently query them to search for **words** and **phrases** anywhere with the text columns without triggering a full table scan.  Depending upon their usage, using LIKE or INSTR will almost always result in a full table scan.

`CONTAINS` is used to search for **words** and **phrases**.  Although there are many options it is not appropriate if you are looking for embedded characters such as 'A' or chr(8211).

The following query will return all rows that contain the word "smith" anywhere in their text.

```
SELECT score(1), p.name
FROM person p
WHERE CONTAINS(p.name, 'smith', 1) > 0;
```

For more details see:

- [How does contains() in PL-SQL work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431054/how-does-contains-in-pl-sql-work)
- [Oracle SQL "contains" clause tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_contains_clause.htm)
- [Oracle: Contains Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/csql.htm#CCREF0104)
- [Oracle: Contains Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cqoper.htm#CCREF0300)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you need to find if a column has any values that have character in it, you can use `regexp_like`. The first parameter is the column name to be checked and the second parameter is the regular expression.

If the below sql returns count greater than zero, that means there are some row(s) in which there is 1 or more character in it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE regexp_like (COLUMN_NAME, '[^0-9]')
```