# Oracle CONTAINS issue

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search, contains, oracle12.2

so I'm stumped here.  I'm using Oracle 12.2.

Say I have 2 records in table "t" where the SEARCH_NAME column is indexed by type CONTEXT:

```
SEARCH_NAME
-----------------
REED, JAMES D
REED, JAMES J
```

I want to search for the first record (REED, JAMES D) using the CONTAINS operator. I would've expected this to work, but it does not as it will return both records. Anyone have any idea how to get only the first?

```
SELECT search_name
  FROM contacts 
 WHERE CONTAINS(search_name, 'REED\, JAMES D') > 0;
```

Comment: This is probably because the full text index ignores single letter words.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT search_name
  FROM contacts 
 WHERE CONTAINS(search_name, 'REED\, JAMES D', 1) > 0;
```

Find more on:

[Contains for String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346551/use-string-contains-function-in-oracle-sql-query/20346741)

[How contains works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431054/how-does-contains-in-pl-sql-work)