# Select rows that do not contain a word from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with one word each row and a table with some text in a row. I need
to select from the second table only those rows that does not contain words from the first table.

For example:

Table with constratint words

| constraint_word |
| --- |
| example |
| apple |
| orange |
| mushroom |
| car |
| qwerty |

Table with text

| text |
| --- |
| word1. **apple**; word3, **example** |
| word1, **apple**, word2. **car** |
| word1 word2 **orange** word3 |
| **mushroom**word1 word2 word3 |
| word1 **car** |
| **qwerty** |

Nothing should be selected in this case, because every row in the second table contains words from the first table.

I only have an idea to use `CROSS JOIN` to achive this

```
SELECT DISTINCT text FROM text_table CROSS JOIN words_table
           WHERE CONTAINS(text, constraint_word ) = 0
```

Is there a way to do it without using `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I use Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contains` means Oracle Text; cross join means Cartesian product (usually performance nightmare).

One option which avoids both of these is `instr` function (which checks existence of the `constraint_word` in `text`, but this time using inner join) and the `minus` set operator.

Something like this, using sample data you posted:

```
SQL> select * from text_table;

TEXT
---------------------------
word1.apple; word3, example
word1, apple, word2.car
word1 word2 orange word3
mushroomword1 word2 word3
word1 car
qwerty

6 rows selected.

SQL> select * From words_table;

CONSTRAI
--------
example
apple
orange
mushroom
car
qwerty

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

As you said, initially query shouldn't return anything because all `constraint_words` exist in `text`:

```
SQL> select c.text
  2  from text_table c
  3  minus
  4  select b.text
  5  from words_table a join text_table b on instr(b.text, a.constraint_word) > 0;

no rows selected
```

Let's modify one of `text` rows:

```
SQL> update text_table set text = 'xxx' where text = 'qwerty';

1 row updated.
```

What's the result now?

```
SQL> select c.text
  2  from text_table c
  3  minus
  4  select b.text
  5  from words_table a join text_table b on instr(b.text, a.constraint_word) > 0;

TEXT
---------------------------
xxx

SQL>
```

Right; text we've just modified.

Comment: Although performance is better for `INSTR`, the matching differs: `CONTAINS` will respect certain grammar constraints like e.g. word-boundaries, whereas `INSTR` also matches `mushroomword1` (where 'mushroom' is not an entire word, but partial match).

Comment: @hc_dev, sample data (see line #4, "**mushroom**word1 ...") suggest that partial match is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is fine, since you need to test all words for each text.
This is what CROSS JOIN does - a combination (cartesian product).

We can even be more restrictive for better performance and use INNER JOIN, or the shorthand `JOIN`.

See also: [CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759687/ddg#21794288)

Additionally you need to filter all `text` records, where there are no matches at all. This means the **count of non-matches** over all combinations per `text` is maximum (= number of constraint_words, here 6).
This filter can be done using `GROUP BY` WITH `HAVING`

```sql
-- text without any constaint_word
SELECT t.text, count(*)
FROM text_table t
JOIN words_table w ON CONTAINS(t.text, w.constraint_word, 1) = 0
GROUP BY t.text
HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM words_table)
;
```

It will output:

| text | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| **mushroom**word1 word2 word3 | 6 |

Try the demo on on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e31632/2)

#### Entire-word vs partial matches

Note that 'mushroom' from constraint words is not matched by `CONTAINS` because it is contained as *word-part* not as entire word.

For partial-matches you can use `INSTR` as [answered by Littlefoot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70746988/5730279).

#### See also

- [Use string contains function in oracle SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346551/use-string-contains-function-in-oracle-sql-query/20346741)
- [How does contains() in PL-SQL work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431054/how-does-contains-in-pl-sql-work)
- [Oracle context indexes](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_context_index.htm)
- [Creating and Maintaining Oracle Text Indexes](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/text/CreateIndexes/CreatingTextIndexes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works (I think the issue with the `CROSS JOIN` route is that it includes any texts that don't contain *at least one* of the words--not just texts that don't contain any):

```
SELECT DISTINCT text FROM text_table WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM words_table WHERE CONTAINS(text, constraint_word)) = 0;
```